# Improve performance for reading CSV file from ZIP?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

Do you have any idea how to improve the performance by reading CSV file from a zip file?

Firstly it open the zip file, then put the data into a memory and then read it by `fgetcsv`

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($fileName)) {
    $info = $zip->statIndex(0);
    $fp = $zip->getStream($info['name']);
    if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $contents .= fread($fp, 2);
    }
        fclose($fp);
        $zip->close();
}

$temp = fopen("php://memory", "rw");
fwrite($temp, $contents);
fseek($temp, 0);

while (($data = fgetcsv($temp, 0)) !== false) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: Why do you read it and put it in memory? You can fgetcsv on the first run.

Comment: Because  CSV file are stored in a zip file, that is why it put in the memory for `fgetcsv` to read?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back, you sound like don't actually have a real reason for buffering into memory. Are you suggesting fgetcsv() didn't work until you first buffered into memory?

Comment: Also consider to take a look into http://php.net/SplFileObject which gives an easy interface on CSV data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick check with php manual showed that this should work:

```
<?php

    $fp = fopen('zip://test.zip#test', 'r'); // test  name of file in archive
    if (!$fp) {
        exit("cannot open\n");
    }
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 0)) !== false) {
        ...
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: sorry missed `zip://`. Should be before your path.

Comment: You might need full path so use `__DIR__` (`dirname(__FILE__)` for < 5.3 PHP) to get relative path.

Comment: Not sure about speed but should improve memory usage.

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getnameindex.php` to iterate through files in archive

Comment: What if I don't know the name of a file

Comment: @Sohaib Check http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getnameindex.php It'll let you iterate over archive.